# Unable to proceed with Twilio Programmable Video Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, twilio

I am new to Twilio and facing few problems. I have downloaded twilio programmable video SDK Javascript version for my web app and it works pretty fine however I am unable to figure out how I can enable different users to create conversations and invite people. I want Many to Many relationship and don't know if twilio video supports it or not. Any help would be highly appreciated. Please share any tutorial as well.

Here is the code which i Got from Twilio website for JS/C#

```
public string generate_token()
{
    string AccountSid = "SID";
    string ApiKeySid = "APIKEY";
    string ApiKeySecret = "APISECRET";
    const string ConfigurationProfileSid = "klinik";

    // Create an Access Token
    var token = new AccessToken(AccountSid, ApiKeySid, ApiKeySecret);

    // Set the Identity of this token
    token.Identity = "example-user";

    // Grant access to Conversations
    var grant = new ConversationsGrant();
    grant.ConfigurationProfileSid = ConfigurationProfileSid;
    token.AddGrant(grant);

    return token.ToJWT().ToString();

    // Serialize the token as a JWT
  //  Console.WriteLine(token.ToJWT());
}
```

I am getting the following error on .ToJWT function in visual studio:

Error   CS0012  The type 'JwtHashAlgorithm' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'JWT, Version=1.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's difficult to help you any further as you haven't shared any code or anything you've tried.

The [JavaScript quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-js) is the best example of how to get started with the Video SDK. I recommend taking a look through the code to see how it is built.

To make many to many conversations, you just need to [invite another user to an existing conversation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/conversations#invite-a-new-participant) or [invite many users at one time](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/conversations#invite-multiple-clients). Make sure you invite them from all the existing participants as this is a peer to peer connection, so every user needs to create a connection with every other user. For that reason, it's not recommended to make many to many conversations of more than 4 people total (though you should test to see what kind of results you get).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Dear philnas, thanks for your response. I have updated my question and I have also downloaded quickstart app for javascript c# and when I run my project it gives error for missing local.config file. Quick start project does not have any local.config file due to which I am facing the problem in executing it. Hope you will help me out in resolving the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# I'm afraid. Perhaps my colleague @devin-rader can help, he knows more about that!

Comment: It would be great if he can help me out as me and my team are stuck into the problem and are not getting much help on internet about twilio programmable video.